# Python import good practice?

Tags: python, import

For my current python projects, I currently add this lines of code at the beginning of each scripts :

```
import os
import sys
current = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
(__,folder) = os.path.split(current)
while folder != "my_root_folder_name":
    current = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current, os.path.pardir))
    (__, folder) = os.path.split(current)
sys.path.insert(0, current)
```

Here *my_root_folder_name* is the name of the root folder of the project. Having this in every script allows to import any of them from any other of them by writing (wherever the importing script is):

```
import subfolder1.subfolder2.thescript
```

Where *subfolder1* is in the root folder *my_root_folder_name* (final path is */my_root_folder_name/subfolder1/subfolder2/thescript.py*).

Is that a good practice ? Do you see any disadvantage of this trick ? What better option do I have ?

**EDIT:** Let say my project is organised as follow:

- in the main folder, I have subfolders *src*, *data*, *models*, *logs*, *config*...
- in *src* I have a main script 'my_project.py' and subsubfolders *data*, *models*, *features*.

The reason I use this trick is to make sure I can import a script of a subfolder from one another subfolder. This might lead to circular imports if you don't pay attention, but python '..' syntax for imports does as well. It also makes the imports clearer, since every import is done by writing the entire absolute path to the script.

**EDIT 2:** **This piece of code doesn't import every other scripts !!**. It just replaces the first (index 0) sys.path value of the script, which is the actual folder where the file is, by the main folder of the project.

Comment: Have a look at the `imp` lib for custom path imports. Might actually be a better approach.

Comment: why do you do that? You should import directly the your local file, `import my_wonderful_module`.

Comment: @gunzapper  I edited my question.

Comment: IMHO it is not a good practice and I never seen it before (in more than 10 year). I will hope you do not do circular imports...

Comment: I don't, but you're right when saying it might allow circular imports. But python allows it anyway with the '..' syntax, doesn't it ?

Comment: But is it not better to import only modules that you use? Is every module in the other sub folders use by every modules of each sub folders? (Note that it is circular). You could design it better

Comment: Ok I do a second edit to make things clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148068/discussion-between-gunzapper-and-debzsud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of your approach doesn't justify the cost. The benefit is that you can write

```
import subfolder1.subfolder2.thescript
```

everywhere instead of some variant of

```
from ..subfolder2 import thescript
```

The cost is that everyone reading your code must now figure out the answers to questions like

- What happens if you change the root directory name?
- Could the root directory ever be missing?
- Is there any way the loop can fail to terminate?
- Is there any problem if many modules add the same folder to the head of sys.path?
- Have I thought of all the potential problems with this code? Perhaps I should ask Stack Overflow ;-).

Once Joe Programmer is convinced the code is bug free and has no bad implications, he can copy and paste it without thinking. But is it worth adding 5 lines of not-so-obvious boilerplate in order to avoid a slightly-ugly import syntax Joe already needs to understand? No.

Choose one of these well-understood options:

- Use relative import syntax.
- Use absolute import syntax
  and always run your code from a script in your project root directory.
  Python automatically adds the main script's directory to the path.
- Use absolute import syntax
  and always run your code from a wrapper that sets the path.
  This way any directory-search tricks are kept in a single file.

Comment: Good point and nice options summarization. You get the bounty !

Answer (score 4):

Generally no, this would not be good practice for a few reasons.

1. You should only be importing the packages which are absolutely required for each file. Importing unnecessary packages can cause performance issues as well as having possibly confusing code.
2. You're adding a loop to your code, in every file, for no real required reason. This isn't good practice and depending on how many dependencies you have can slow you down.
3. You're requiring a file to be located in your root folder, and using the os paths to get to it, generally not good performance wise if you can avoid it.

Comment: Could you provide an example where it might use to much resources ? The loop only iterates over the paths, and do not import anything, that's why I don't understand your points 1 and 2. Point 3 is unclear to me. Do you mean that I take the risk to create a loop of import ?

Comment: @debzsud From the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead) - "import statements can be executed just about anywhere. It's often useful to place them inside functions to restrict their visibility and/or reduce initial startup time. Although Python's interpreter is optimized to not import the same module multiple times, repeatedly executing an import statement can seriously affect performance in some circumstances.".... If you are importing the same packages into every file whether it needs it or not it can cause serious overhead

Comment: Then I might repeat myself but, I do not import several times, I just change the system path such that all my files are located in the root folder. If I'm misunderstanding something please be more precise.

Comment: If I have file 'a' and file 'b'. In file 'a' I need packages: numpy, seaborn, and pandas. In file 'b' I need packages: numpy.

If I were to use the import method you are suggesting, in file 'b' I would be importing 2 extra packages (seaborn, pandas) that I do not need. This would cause unneed overhead, as well as cause possible issues with variable names. It is not a good practice.

Comment: I don't import every scripts, just change their sys.paths.

Answer (score 1):

Does the solution need to be written inside the Python code itself?

Setting `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/module/root` does exactly what you want.  For example:

```
$ find /tmp/py/modules/ -type f
/tmp/py/modules/qwerty/a/b/target.py
/tmp/py/modules/asdf/a/b/source

$ pwd
/tmp/py/modules/asdf

$ python /tmp/py/modules/asdf/a/b/source
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/py/modules/asdf/a/b/source", line 3, in <module>
    import qwerty.a.b.target
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qwerty'

$ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/py/modules/ 

$ python /tmp/py/modules/asdf/a/b/source
Hello from target
```

**/tmp/py/modules/qwerty/a/b/target.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ("Hello from target")
```

**/tmp/py/modules/asdf/a/b/source**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import qwerty.a.b.target
```

The solution is in fact the same as what you're doing, just outside of Python code.

Note that for Python2, you would need to create `__init__.py` files on each directory in the structure (the files may be empty).  Python3's documentation also says they're required but the example above worked just fine without them.

The updated directory contents would be as follows:

```
./qwerty/__init__.py
./qwerty/a/__init__.py
./qwerty/a/b/__init__.py
./qwerty/a/b/target.py
./asdf/__init__.py
./asdf/a/__init__.py
./asdf/a/b/__init__.py
./asdf/a/b/source
```

(the files `__init__.py` are not strictly required under `asdf` for this simple example, but as you want to be able to import all scripts from all others, that's how you would do in your project)

As an addtional note, if you keep your Python code above, my only suggestion would be to check for reaching the root folder, lest you end up in an infinite loop in the case where the script was moved and `my_root_folder_name` is not a component of its new location's path.  For UNIX, I'd do something like this:

```
if current == "/":
    raise Exception ("Module folder not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago. In my opinion, this is a problem of the Python language that get complicated in a simple action like import statements. I done the same choise to solve the problem, update the PYTHONPATH enviroment variable via `sys.path` command. I do in a different way to you, i write a recursive folder explorer and put it into `__init__.py` in the root folder of your project. The code is the following:

```
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path


def recursive_explorer(path):
    sys.path.append(path)
    subfolders = [subfile for subfile in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(path / subfile)]
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        recursive_explorer(path / subfolder)


recursive_explorer(Path(__file__).parent / 'your_src_folder')
```

I think my solution is good because is portable and you need to write once.

Comment: What is the effect of setting this in the __init__.py file ? Does this apply to all subscripts of the project ?

Comment: This script do the same thing of your code at the starting of each script.`__init__.py` is a Python file executed automatically before your scripts and it is used to inizialize a package represented by folder (you can find a complete explain here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Simply explore each subfolder that contains your python files and add every path to the PYTHONPATH enviroment variable. The advantage is that you need to write this only once in your project root.

Comment: An alternative that allow you to avoid the update of PYTHONPATH depends from your IDE: if you use PyCharm you can set in the project settings you can communicate to the IDE which is your src folder and then you can avoid the entire path for import a python file.

Comment: The thing is that the projects I build are then deployed on multiple servers and called by other scripts. So I need something quit generic. But you're solution differs from mine because you need to call directly the file name, not the the full path from the root, it can create more conflicts (is it ?).